# How can i set max count of pods for replication-controller per node?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a question.

Let's imagine a situation.

For example: We have three node within the cluster.
And we have replication-controller where we have spec: replicas: 3

I would like to have not more one pod per node.
Because if one node will have more one pod while node die, i'll lose two or more pods.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The Kubernetes scheduler already prioritizes spreading pods from the same replication controller out across your nodes.

However, if you want to be 100% sure that no two pods will end up on the same node, you can set the container's `HostPort` field. No two containers with the same `HostPort` can ever run on the same node.

If you want to get even fancier, you could write your own scheduler plugin :)

In general, though, the idea of Kubernetes is that you shouldn't have to think about your nodes except in special circumstances; you can instead trust the system to keep your applications running.

Comment: `> The Kubernetes scheduler already prioritizes spreading pods from the same replication controller out across your nodes`

beginning with commit?
i build 0.18.0
and the scheduler run half of my pods on first node :/

`> However, if you want to be 100% sure that no two pods will end up on the same node`

it's not in my case
because i use a overlay network (flannel)

Comment: I'm sorry, spreading happens by service rather than by replication controller. Perhaps you should try defining a service for your set of labels before creating the replication controller? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/plugin/pkg/scheduler/algorithm/priorities/spreading.go#L36